# popToRootViewController brings last view over navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am running into a weird issue which when i use back functionality in my navigation hierarchy using

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

it works fine and navigation is smooth but I am using popToRootViewController so as to perform 'Back to Home' functionality from that same viewcontroller it brings the header of that view controller over the navigation bar after navigation is done Although I am on the root view controller i am using translucent navigation bar as a navigation bar The structure i am following is my HomeViewController is root view controller while rest all of the view controllers are pushed on to that root view controller.however i use this code in my SideMenuViewController which added as a child view controller onto my Navigation hierarchy.
i am using the following line to return to home.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope my question is clear now.
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.thanks in advance.below image explains how it looks like after using popToRootViewController.
[image: this is how my view looks like after popToRootViewController]

Comment: Buddy need some code and more explanation. Most probably your view controller stack is that way.

Comment: Please suggest now I have improved it a bit.

Comment: just do two things 1. check if are you using navigation controller in storyboard? 2. Remove SideMenuViewController and check what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your question exactly. But popToRootViewController in the sense, it directly goes to initial view controller(first view when application started). After moves 4 to 5 view controllers if you write popToRootViewController you directly comes to first view.

popToview means you just go back to last view controller what you had seen.

Comment: I understand that but it brings the last popped view controller header to my navigation bar when I am back to root view controller.I have improved the question please take a look now.